# how to find control in ItemTemplate of the ListView from code behind of the usercontrol page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder, user-controls

actually, i'm developing a web template using ASP.NET and C#.
i have a `listview` in a `usercontrol` page and inside the `ItemTemplate` i have a `PlaceHolder` as below:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph_Lv_EditModule" runat="server">  </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

i want to access to this `PlaceHolder` from code behind and i have use different method as below but i couldn't access it.

```
PlaceHolder ph_Lv_EditModule = (PlaceHolder)lv_Uc_Module.FindControl("ph_Lv_EditModule");
```

or

```
PlaceHolder ph_Lv_EditModule = (PlaceHolder)this.lv_Uc_Module.FindControl("ph_Lv_EditModule");
```

could you please help me how to find this control at the code behind of my `usercontrol` page.
appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `ListView` typically contains more than one item, therefore the [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx)(searched by `FindControl`) of your Placeholder is neither the UserControl, nor the ListView itself. It's the [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) object. So one place to find the reference is the [ListView's ItemDataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx).

```
protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var ph_Lv_EditModule = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("ph_Lv_EditModule");
    }
}
```

If you need the reference somewhere else, you must iterate the Items of the ListView and then use `FindControl` on the `ListViewItem`.

By the way, this is the same behaviour as in other DataBound Controls like GridView or Repeater.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Schmelter mentioned, you can also access your control by iterating through your `ListView` as follows

```
private void HideMyEditModule()
{
    foreach (var item in lv_Uc_Module.Items)
    {
        PlaceHolder holder = item.FindControl("ph_Lv_EditModule") as PlaceHolder;
        if (holder!= null)
            holder.Visible = false;
    }
}
```