# using string as control id in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

i have a page with 2 textbox items and a button
textbox1 contains a word , and textbox2 is empty

now i want to put content of TextBox1.Text in TextBox2.Text with button click,

i tried:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ Page.FindControl("TextBox2").Text = TextBox1.Text; }
```

this code don't work ,how to make this work?

Comment: `FindControl` does not recursively search containers so maybe it is not a direct child of Page. Why not just `TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;` ?

Comment: real use case is more complicated and will take long lines to describe , is there any other valid method ? , in windows forms i used to do: this.Controls.Find("textBox2", true)[0].Text = textBox1.Text; , but this don't work in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define it first then apply properties

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    TextBox textBox2 = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox2");
    textBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox textbox2= (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(Page, "TextBox2");
```

try using this, referencing [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327229/asp-net-find-control-by-id)