# 'username' does not exist in it's current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

The ID is inside the `ItemTemplate` and it cannot be found in the code file.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="searchresults" runat="server"
                       ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:AgileDatabaseConnection %>'
                       SelectCommand=" SELECT [userID], [userName], [firstName],[lastName],[password], [email] FROM [Users] WHERE ([email] LIKE '%' + @email + '%')">
        <selectparameters>
            <asp:querystringparameter querystringfield="searchquery" name="email" type="String"></asp:querystringparameter>
        </selectparameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:ListView ID="displayitems" runat="server" DataSourceID="searchresults">
        <itemtemplate>
            <asp:label runat="server" associatedcontrolid="projectOwner" cssclass="col-md-2 control-label">Project Owner:</asp:label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ProjectOwner" CssClass="form-control" /><br />
                <asp:label runat="server" associatedcontrolid="projectOwner" cssclass="col-md-2 control-label">Scrum Master:</asp:label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ScrumMaster" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:AgileDatabaseConnection %>' SelectCommand="SELECT userName FROM [Users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="usertype" DataSourceID="ScrumMaster" DataTextField="userName"></asp:dropdownlist><br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <asp:label runat="server" cssclass="col-md-2 control-label">Email:</asp:label>
            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' runat="server" ID="emaillabel" /><br />
            <asp:label runat="server" cssclass="col-md-2 control-label">UserName:</asp:label>
            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("userName") %>' runat="server" ID="username" /><br />

            <asp:label runat="server" cssclass="col-md-2 control-label">UserID:</asp:label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("userID") %>' ID="UserID" CssClass="form-control" />
            <br />
            <div class="actions"></div>

            <asp:Button Text="Add" runat="server" class="btn pull-right" ID="uploadbutton" OnClick="add_Click"></asp:Button>
            </div>
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <emptydatatemplate>

        <span>No users match  <asp:Label Text='' runat="server" ID="email" /> .</span>

    </emptydatatemplate>
</form>
```

C# says it can't find 'userName'. Here's my backend code:

```
string ownerName = ProjectOwner.Text;
string IDuser = username.Text;
string IDdata = Session["userID"].ToString();
```

How do I get the userName value through?

Comment: the other fields are well resolved?

Comment: there is a second SqlDataSource inside ListView

Comment: Hi sorry i didn't post that the projectowner isn't resolved either.

Comment: The error is about Text='<%#Eval("userName") %>', not about ID=username

Comment: the name 'ProjectOwner' does not exist in the current context
the name 'username' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Inside a list view there are a lot of ProjectOwners and UserNames controls, you cannot use it as an unique control identifier, you should iterate through ListView items at server side.

Comment: See, we moved the code on the front end around, which did resolve the c# but then there was issues with the item template on the front end and when I resolved the itemtemplate issue on the front end the projectowner and username isn't resolved in the back end.

Comment: First, use only one DataSource, then take a look at this post, you'll find some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208528/how-to-find-control-in-itemtemplate-of-the-listview-from-code-behind-of-the-user

Comment: and another example from MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: Is this code behind inside the `ListView`'s `ItemDataBound`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ListView` can return more then one item, so code behind doesn't know about which of the itens controls (username and ProjectOwner) are you talking about.

If you want to do the same thing for EACH item, you can do like this:

```
protected void displayitems_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        string ownerName = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("ProjectOwner")).Text;
        string IDuser = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("username").Text;
        string IDdata = Session["userID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: We are now getting errors under the FindControl

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemViewEventArgs' does not contain a definition for FindControl and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemViewEventArgs' could be found

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemViewEventArgs' does not contain a definition for FindControl and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemViewEventArgs' could be found

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add one thing. Will edit, just a sec

Comment: Anytime. Glad I could help.